# calling signal handler again in itself

Tags: c, linux, signals

I see a code illustrating how to do safe signal handling. A point I don't understand that why the signal handler calls again `signal (sig, catch_alarm);`. What's the reason to do that? Without it, the code works too.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>


/* This flag controls termination of the main loop. */
volatile sig_atomic_t keep_going = 1;

/* The signal handler just clears the flag and re-enables itself. */
void
catch_alarm (int sig)
{
    keep_going = 0;
    signal (sig, catch_alarm);   //  <----- ???
}

void
do_stuff (void)
{
    puts ("Doing stuff while waiting for alarm....");
}

int
main (void)
{
    /* Establish a handler for SIGALRM signals. */
    signal (SIGALRM, catch_alarm);

    /* Set an alarm to go off in a little while. */
    alarm (2);

    /* Check the flag once in a while to see when to quit. */
    while (keep_going)
        do_stuff ();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the behaviour of `signal()` varies across UNIX versions, and has also varied historically across different versions of Linux (quoted from Linux man). Especially:

> In the original UNIX systems, when a handler that was established using
>          signal()  was  invoked  by the delivery of a signal, the disposition of
>          the signal would be reset to SIG_DFL, and  the  system  did  not  block
>          delivery  of  further  instances  of the signal.  This is equivalent to
>          calling sigaction(2) with the following flags:
>
> sa.sa_flags = SA_RESETHAND | SA_NODEFER;

So in such a system you have to call `signal()` again after a signal has been delivered. Because of these portability issues, the man page starts with:

> The behavior of signal() varies across UNIX versions, and has also varied historically across different versions of Linux.   Avoid  its  use:
>         use sigaction(2) instead.  See Portability below.

Answer (score 1):

To put it simply: *You're wrong and the code is wrong.*

Or, you assume that the `signal` call is superfluous - it isn't, and exists there to make the code behave correctly on platforms that use THE other allowed `signal` semantics.

Also, the excerpt is not about **safe signal handling with `signal` function**; 
it is about how to pass an event out from a signal handler - for which there is only *one* portable way - by changing a variable of type `volatile sig_atomic_t`. To write safe portable code now, you'd use the function `sigaction`.

---

The Linux [`signal(2)` manuals say](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html):

> The behavior of `signal()` varies across UNIX versions, and has also
>          varied historically across different versions of Linux.  Avoid its
>          use: use `sigaction(2)` instead.

and

> The  only  portable  use of `signal()` is to set a signal's disposition to `SIG_DFL` or `SIG_IGN`.
>          The semantics when using `signal()` to establish a signal handler  vary  across  systems  (and
>          POSIX.1 explicitly permits this variation); **do not use it for this purpose.**
>
> ***POSIX.1 solved the portability mess by specifying `sigaction(2)`, which
>          provides explicit control of the semantics when a signal handler is
>          invoked; use that interface instead of `signal()`.***

And

> The situation on Linux is as follows:
>
> - The kernel's signal() system call provides System V semantics.
> - By default, in glibc 2 and later, the `signal()` wrapper function does not invoke the kernel
>          system call.  Instead, it calls `sigaction(2)` using flags that supply BSD semantics.   This
>          default  behavior  is  provided  as  long  as  a  suitable  feature test macro is defined:
>          `_BSD_SOURCE` on glibc 2.19 and earlier or `_DEFAULT_SOURCE` in glibc  2.19  and  later.   (By
>          default,  these  macros  are  defined; see feature_test_macros(7) for details.)  If such a
>          feature test macro is not defined, then `signal()` provides System V semantics.

Now the question is *which one is defined*. If you compile with `-std=c11` you will get the *resetting semantics*, because it doesn't set the `_DEFAULT_SOURCE`! And then you need to rearm the `SIG_ALARM` *every time*.

The purpose of resetting the signal in the signal handler is that some Unixen clear the handler whenever the signal is triggered. There are also other interesting edge cases - the only reason to use this function is that it is in the *C standard*, but its behaviour isn't well-specified there either. **Never use it to set a custom signal handler.**

---

As the code says, **both** of these `signal` calls should be frowned upon. Good modern code <s>should</s>must use `sigaction` instead, for example

```
struct sigaction newsigfunc;
newsigfunc.sa_handler = catch_alarm;
sigemptyset(&newsigfunc.sa_mask);
newsigfunc.sa_flags = 0;

sigaction(SIGALRM, &newsigfunc, NULL);
```

`sigaction`, unlike `signal`, will guarantee portability here; wherever it doesn't exist, `signal` is likely to misbehave too...

Comment: "man 2 signal" on my Ubuntu computer says "SIG_IGN, SIG_DFL, or the address of a  programmer-defined  function (a "signal handler")".

Comment: In other words, this code is fully correct for Linux, but not necessarily on other systems.

Comment: "Not portable" isn't "wrong" as such. Obviously `sigaction` is preferable but glibc (Linux) has long been using BSD semantics for signals and using `signal` doesn't have any issues (other than providing lesser control compared to `sigaction`).

Comment: The code is taken from GNU. https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Handler-Returns.html#Handler-Returns

Comment: @ArndtJonasson whatever.

Comment: @P.P. No, **Linux** has always used and still uses **System V semantics**. Glibc uses BSD semantics with `_DEFAULT_SOURCE` - but not otherwise.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Glibc provided BSD semantics even before `_DEFAULT_SOURCE` existed by default (`_GNU_SOURCE` is sufficient). At least since glibc 2.2.3 that's been the case.

Comment: @P.P. I read that too. The man pages say very clearly that `_DEFAULT_SOURCE` from now on, and whatever will *set that*, and you're missing my point completely. You said that It very specifically isn't the behaviour of *Linux* but of Glibc and only with flags. If compiled with any other libc implementation, all bets are off...

Comment: glibc is the default libc on pretty much all Linux distros. If we are talking about a different libc, then all these macros are not quite relevant. And "behaviour of Linux" makes no sense without stating the libc we're talking about, either.

Comment: @P.P. of course it makes sense. Please recite your Stallman: *"There is no system but GNU, and Linux is one of its kernels."*

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is the original Unix implementation would **reset** the signal handler to it's default value after signal is received. The code here simply  demonstrate this.

```
signal (sig, catch_alarm);
```